# FFPROBE not supported on window machine

Tags: laravel

I'm using the `PHP-FFMpeg` repository to do some video work inside my Laravel application, but I'm encountering some issues setting it up

> ffprobe failed to execute command

```
return [
    'default_disk' => 'local',

'ffmpeg' => [
   // 'binaries' => env('FFMPEG_BINARIES', 'ffmpeg'),
    'ffmpeg.binaries'  => 'C:/binaries/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe',
    'threads' => 12,
],

'ffprobe' => [
    //'binaries' => env('FFPROBE_BINARIES', 'ffprobe'),
    'ffprobe.binaries' => 'C:/binaries/ffmpeg/bin/ffprobe.exe',
],

'timeout' => 3600,
];
```

[image]

Comment: You need to look at the logs for *why* these jobs failed.

Comment: `ffprobe.binaries` should probably just be `binaries`, too. Same for the `ffmpeg.binaries`. It was correct in the lines you commented out.